# latest version of Entity framework vs NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

considering the latest version of Entity framework as against NHibernate, is there a reason why I should use NHibernate as opposed to the latest version of Entity framework?

Are there features of Nhibernate that is not covered by current version of Entity framework?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are tons of posts about differences between NH and EF - do some yourselves research if you want to get complete answer.

Short version:

EF 4.1 brings only new way to use EF 4.0 - it means new simplified API called (DbContext) and code mapping. Both these new features are more limited than original EF 4.0.

EF 4.3 brings code-first migrations for incremental data model development.

EF 4.5 Beta / EF 5.0 Beta brings support for enums, spatial types, table valued functions, auto compiled queries + performance and API improvements.

There are a lot of NH's features which are still not possible in EF

- More possibilities for complex mapping
- Custom type mapping
- Batch command execution
- Future queries
- 2nd level cache
- Extensibility and a lot of ready to use extensions
- A lot of hooks where you can replace NH's default implementation with your own or add new logic
- etc.

EF has better LINQ support and it is from MS - for many companies this is important decision point. You can check [data user voice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions) to see what features are currently requested from ADO.NET team for next releases.